# Key Value pair storage in Settings file

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Key Value Storage in Settings file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166496/key-value-storage-in-settings-file)

Hi, 
 I am developing an application in C#, which needs to store an array of key value pair in settings file.Looking for a perfect solution 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166496/key-value-storage-in-settings-file ?

Comment: You need to define your criteria for perfection more precisely as there are inevitably tradeoffs involved. For example, do you prefer speedy loading of the settings file or human readability?

Comment: why you duplicate question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166496/key-value-storage-in-settings-file/1166548#1166548

Answer (score 0):

What about using something like MemcacheDB?